# <apex:image/> tag in a Visualforce page shows broken images with renderAs="pdf"

Tags: visualforce

Can anyone please advise what could be the reason behind the broken image when using the image tag this way with renderAs PDF?(Works fine if we remove renderAs="pdf")

[image]

If this is used in static resources it loads just fine. However, I am wondering why this fails to render outside of static resources especially if using static resources is not a solution for anyone because the reason could be url of the image might be generated dynamically

Can be reproduced by a simple test VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Developments__c"  renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:image url="https://www.millerhomes.co.uk/-/media/developments/scotland/developments/lapwing-brae/house-types-and-floor-plans/haig.jpg" width="180" style="display:block;padding-bottom:0;" />
    <img src="https://www.millerhomes.co.uk/-/media/developments/scotland/developments/lapwing-brae/house-types-and-floor-plans/haig.jpg" width="180" style="display:block;padding-bottom:0;" />
</apex:page>
```

Note: Fails to load with advanced_pdf as well

Comment: Have a remote site setting set up for this website and the trusted IPs should all be within the range. However, it still doesn't work

Comment: This callout can be simulated in the dev console by executing the following:

HTTPRequest req=new HTTPRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://www.millerhomes.co.uk/-/media/corporate/corporate-2018/calum--ross.jpg');
req.setMethod('GET');

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getStatus());

Callout fails with the exception
System.CalloutException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. This is a certificate issue with the target host